# netsnmp "snmptable" command retrieves excessive MIB objects

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I have implemented different custom MIBs by using net-snmp-5.7.3 package. As an example, custom OIDs are as below:

- .1.3.6.1.4.1.XXXXXX.1.1 //scalar
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.XXXXXX.1.2 //scalar
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.XXXXXX.3.2 //table
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.XXXXXX.6.1 //scalar
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.XXXXXX.6.2 //scalar
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.XXXXXX.6.3 //scalar

For the type of string mibs, I registered the instance as below:

```
    reginfo = netsnmp_create_handler_registration("fwVersion",   handle_fwVersion, fwVersion_oid, OID_LENGTH(fwVersion_oid),HANDLER_CAN_RWRITE);

watcher_flags = WATCHER_SIZE_STRLEN;
netsnmp_init_watcher_info6(&watcher_info, fwVersion, strlen(fwVersion),
                           ASN_OCTET_STR, watcher_flags,
                           sizeof(fwVersion), NULL);
netsnmp_register_watched_instance(reginfo, &watcher_info);
```

snmpget command works correctly for scalars. However, snmptable command retrieves not only the table OIDs but also the following scalar handlers are called wrongly.

I have referred the data_set example which is http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/dev/agent/data_set_8c-example.html

In addition, I have tried to implement with different mib2c table configuration templates.

Interestingly, If I retrieve the example mibs offered in the net-snmp package (e.g. data_set, netSnmpHostsTable), again my custom handlers (since they all have subsequent OIDs) are called wrongly.

How to prevent snmptable to call other mib object handlers wrongly ? Is this failure of snmptable command?

Comment: What exactly are the commands you are talking about? Show them and we can see if you use the wrong ones.

Comment: Dear @LexLi, thanks for interest. I used "snmptable" command for table OID,  "snmpget" command for scalar OIDs with **default parameters**. Both command outputs are OK, no error regarding command usage. The problem is after the table OID process is finished, it calls next OID handlers excessively. I recognized the problem after adding debug logs into my custom mibs. It increases the command reply time.  
Note: When I use snmptable with -CB option, the problem still exists however it only calls the next scalar OID as 4 times (my column number is 6 including index)

Comment: Is it so difficult just to cut and paste the exact commands you use?

Comment: The commands with default parameters (no extra parameters are given) could easily be found in net-snmp wiki pages if you are familiar the concept. In case you could not find, I can copy the exact command here from http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptable  
"snmptable -v 2c -c demopublic -Os **"remote_host"** **.1.3.6.1.4.1.XXXXXX.3.2**"

The bold parts are different from the site in my command. However, it should be clear for you why it is so.

Comment: There is not much you can do here, but to dump the packets (`-d` switch) and analyze. A properly implemented SNMP agent should set "end of table" flag to tell `snmptable` to stop at the right place, while a buggy agent can mislead it.